# Match node with a related node with parameters or no related node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm having issues working out a query to match on the following data:

Assume we have the following nodes in the database

```
CREATE (:FOO{y:1,x:1.0})
CREATE (:FOO{y:1,x:2.0})
CREATE (:FOO{y:1,x:3.0})
CREATE (:FOO{y:1,x:4.0})
CREATE (:FOO{y:1,x:5.0})
CREATE (:DERP{y:1,x:2.5})
CREATE (:DERP{y:1,x:6.0})
```

And the nodes are joined by [:BAR] in ascending order of x. So the graph looks like

```
(:FOO{x:1.0})-[:BAR]->(:FOO{x:2.0})-[:BAR]->(:FOO{x:3.0})-[:BAR]->(:FOO{x:4.0})-[:BAR]->(:FOO{x:5.0})
```

The problem is then creating the [:BAR] relationship for the :DERP nodes. They should be related such that (p:FOO)-[:BAR]->(q:DERP) where p.x <= q.x AND (p:FOO)-[:BAR]->(n:FOO) where n.x > q.x   OR  where p.x <= q.x AND NOT (p:FOO)-[:BAR]->()

Trying to put it another way, we have the :FOO nodes joined by relation :BAR and the :DERP nodes should be linked to the :FOO node with x less than or equal to :DERP{x} where the next node related by :BAR has x greater than  :DERP{x}

So at the end we'd have

```
                                    __[:BAR]->(:DERP{y:1,x:2.5})
                                   /
(:FOO{x:1.0})-[:BAR]->(:FOO{x:2.0})-[:BAR]->(:FOO{x:3.0})-[:BAR]->(:FOO{x:4.0})-[:BAR]->(:FOO{x:5.0})->[:BAR]-(:DERP{y:1,x:6.0})
```

My attempted solution is failing miserably.. I can get it for :DERP{y:2.5} with the following

```
MATCH (a:DERP{y:1,x:2.5})
MATCH (p:FOO{y:1})-[:BAR]->(q:FOO{y:1})
WHERE p.x <= a.x AND q.x > a.x
CREATE (p)-[:BAR]->(a)
```

But that fails in the case where p is the last node in the chain because there's no q:FOO to match. So my next attempt was to try to optional match

```
 MATCH (a:DERP{y:1,x:6.0})
 MATCH (p:FOO{y:1})
    WHERE p.x <= a.x
 OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:BAR]->(q:FOO{y:1})
    WHERE (p.x <= a.x AND q.x > a.x) OR q IS NULL
 CREATE (p)-[:BAR]->(a)
```

I think I understand *why* this doesn't work.. but I can't seem to solve the problem myself. Any help is appreciated and apologies for the long post I'm not quite sure how else to explain it and I can't post examples of the real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your last query isn't working is because you have the WHERE clause on the OPTIONAL MATCH, so it's not filtering out rows.

Remember that OPTIONAL MATCH does not filter out non-matching rows, it sets newly introduced variables (`q`, in this case) to null. A WHERE clause is paired with the preceding clause (MATCH, WITH, or OPTIONAL MATCH), and if you want it to filter out rows, you have to pair it with MATCH or WITH.

For more info, check the top section of [this Neo4j knowledge base article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/why-where-clause-does-not-filter/) on why your where clause doesn't seem to be working.

So all you need is a WITH between your OPTIONAL MATCH and the WHERE:

```
MATCH (a:DERP{y:1,x:6.0})
 MATCH (p:FOO{y:1})
    WHERE p.x <= a.x
 OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:BAR]->(q:FOO{y:1})
 WITH a, p, q
    WHERE (p.x <= a.x AND q.x > a.x) OR q IS NULL
 CREATE (p)-[:BAR]->(a)
```

Now, if you want a more generic query that will work for all your nodes, try something like this:

```
MATCH (f:FOO)
OPTIONAL MATCH (f)-[:BAR]->(ff:FOO)
WITH f, f.x as lower, ff.x as upper
MATCH (d:DERP)
WHERE lower <= d.x and (upper is null or d.x <= upper)
CREATE (f)-[:BAR]->(d)
```